# How to get text from an input element and change some other elements value?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an input element:

```
<input type="text" />
```

How can I get text from this input? and then how to print it somewhere else in the page or how to change text of another element in the page to it?

Comment: What do you mean with set position? Do you want to change the position of the input field dynamically? Or do you want to render the text that was in the input in another element?

Comment: I want to get text from input and set position of text

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an id to input like a < input type="text" id="txtname" >, now in javascript you can get and set text=

$('#txtname').val() <- get text from input
$('#txtname').val('some text') <- set text to input

or

$(input[type="text]").val() but this select all input with type text

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
var inputElem=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
inputElem.style.textAlign='center';
var textInput=inputElem.value;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<input type="text">

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputID">
```

To get text from input box using jquery

```
$('inputID').val();
```

To get text from input box without jquery

```
document.getElementById('inputID').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' name='myInput' id='myInput' />
```

In order to get `input`s value using javascript you need to do select it with `getElementById()` method of `document` object:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
```

Now that you've fetched & stored it in a variable, It seems you want to put it somewhere in page. To achieve this, you should first find the element which you want to change its value & then assign `inputValue` to its `text` or `innerHTML`:

```
//Assume we have an `h1` element in our desired position in the doc
<h1 id="targetPosition">....</h1>
```

Now we'll assign `inputValue` to `h1`:

```
document.getElementById("targetPosition").innerHTML = inputValue;
```